# Localstorage not working on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I have a weird issue getting localstorage working on my android device running JQM.
I should mention that my code works perfectly fine when viewed on a web browser, however on my android it will not receive the variable from localStorage.getItem('visittime').

The script is basically my own little popup window that displays to a user once every minute. 
I store a variable in local storage with the current time stamp. If variable exists, it compares it with the timestamp of now. If its been over a minute, the pop will show again.

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
        storagedate = localStorage.getItem('visittime');
    if(storagedate){
        var diff = now - storagedate;
        if(diff > 60000){
            localStorage.removeItem('visited');
            localStorage.removeItem('visittime');
        }
    }
    var yetVisited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
    if (!yetVisited) {
        $(".welcomewindow").delay(1500).fadeIn("300", function(){
            $(".welcome").css({"margin-left":leftPos,"width":welcomeSetwidth}).fadeIn("300") ;
        });
        $(".welcomeClose").on("click",function(e){
            $(".welcomeshield").fadeOut("300");
            $(".welcome").fadeOut("300");
            localStorage.setItem('visited','yes');
            localStorage.setItem('visittime', new Date().getTime());
        });
    }
}
```

I saw people having somewhat similar issues that resolved it by changing the location of their script to be called before JQM loads or on mobileinit. I haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: what is on("pagecreate") ? does that work in android browsers? (i've not heard of it)

Comment: pagecreate: "Triggered when the page has been created in the DOM (via ajax or other) and after all widgets have had an opportunity to enhance the contained markup." (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)

Comment: Have you got this in your Android APP (mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);) ?? --- you can read more here.  -- https://mytechead.wordpress.com/tag/setdomstorageenabled/

Comment: You can debug it as well, please check https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

Answer (score 0):

try using `sessionStorage.comp='12344';` to set values
and `var value= sessionStorage.comp;` to get them

Comment: How would I delete the session using this? I need to be able to add, read, and delete.

Comment: it's delete once you close the browser. You can save it in a cookie or use: var test = "hello world";
localstorage.storageTest = test; 
var test2 = localstorage.storageTest; to remove localStorage.removeItem('storageTest');

Comment: @user3023313 he is not speeking about browser. He is asking for a mobile device. I have the same issue now and I wonder If It really exist a session or cookies on a mobile device.